# SQL Error: ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis 00907. 00000 - "missing right parenthesis"

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

i am getting error missing right parenthesis when creating these tables using sqldeveloper

```
 CREATE TABLE users (
  USER_ID INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  USERNAME VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  PASSWORD VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  ENABLED tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (USER_ID)
);
CREATE TABLE user_roles (
  USER_ROLE_ID INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  USER_ID INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  AUTHORITY VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (USER_ROLE_ID),
  KEY FK_user_roles (USER_ID),
  CONSTRAINT FK_user_roles FOREIGN KEY (USER_ID) 
  REFERENCES users (USER_ID)
);
```

## update...i have modified data types but same error

```
CREATE TABLE users (
  USER_ID NUMBER(10,0) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  USERNAME VARCHAR2(45) NOT NULL,
  PASSWORD VARCHAR2(45) NOT NULL,
  ENABLED NUMBER(3,0) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (USER_ID)
);
CREATE TABLE user_roles (
  USER_ROLE_ID NUMBER(10,0) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  USER_ID NUMBER(10,0) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  AUTHORITY VARCHAR2(45) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (USER_ROLE_ID),
  KEY FK_user_roles (USER_ID),
  CONSTRAINT FK_user_roles FOREIGN KEY (USER_ID) 
  REFERENCES users (USER_ID)
);
```

Comment: That looks like MySQL (maybe?) but it's not Oracle anyway. Look at your documentation for Oracle datatypes.

Comment: Are you sure you are using Oracle RDBMS? Or are you trying to rewrite it from MySQL to Oracle?

Comment: actually i have created this before..using mysql..now i started using sqldeveloper

Comment: SQL Developer is a client tool and not RDBMS. Once again, which RDBMS are you using?

Comment: Oracle Database 10g Enterprise Edition Release 10.2.0.1.0 - 64bi

Comment: @miranayak `UNSIGNED` is not supported in Oracle.

Answer (score 2):

- **UNSIGNED** is not supported in Oracle.
- ```
  KEY FK_user_roles (USER_ID)
  ```

  is syntactically incorrect.

Create the tables as shown below:

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE users (
  2    USER_ID NUMBER(10,0)  NOT NULL,
  3    USERNAME VARCHAR2(45) NOT NULL,
  4    PASSWORD VARCHAR2(45) NOT NULL,
  5    ENABLED NUMBER(3,0) NOT NULL,
  6    PRIMARY KEY (USER_ID)
  7  );

Table created.

SQL> CREATE TABLE user_roles (
  2    USER_ROLE_ID NUMBER(10,0)  NOT NULL,
  3    USER_ID NUMBER(10,0)  NOT NULL,
  4    AUTHORITY VARCHAR2(45) NOT NULL,
  5    PRIMARY KEY (USER_ROLE_ID),
  6    CONSTRAINT FK_user_roles FOREIGN KEY (USER_ID)
  7    REFERENCES users (USER_ID)
  8  );

Table created.

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

below comment may help you

**Sql Sever**

```
 CREATE TABLE users (
  USER_ID INT/*(10) UNSIGNED*/ NOT NULL,
  USERNAME VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  PASSWORD VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  ENABLED tinyint/*(1)*/ NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (USER_ID)
);

CREATE TABLE user_roles (
  USER_ROLE_ID INT/*(10) UNSIGNED*/ NOT NULL,
  USER_ID INT/*(10) UNSIGNED*/ NOT NULL,
  AUTHORITY VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (USER_ROLE_ID),
  /*KEY FK_user_roles (USER_ID),*/
  CONSTRAINT FK_user_roles FOREIGN KEY (USER_ID) 
  REFERENCES users (USER_ID)
);
```

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9eecb7db59d16c80417c72d1/2185)

**Oracle**

```
CREATE TABLE users (
  USER_ID INT/*(10) UNSIGNED*/ NOT NULL,
  USERNAME VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  PASSWORD VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  ENABLED smallINT/*tinyint(1)*/ NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (USER_ID)
);

CREATE TABLE user_roles (
  USER_ROLE_ID INT/*(10) UNSIGNED*/ NOT NULL,
  USER_ID INT/*(10) UNSIGNED*/ NOT NULL,
  AUTHORITY VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (USER_ROLE_ID),
  /*KEY FK_user_roles (USER_ID),*/
  CONSTRAINT FK_user_roles FOREIGN KEY (USER_ID) 
  REFERENCES users (USER_ID)
);
```

Comment: In which Oracle docs have you seen `tinyint` datatype? And what is the point in posting a non-working SQL Fiddle?

Comment: No. By mistake i rectified it for sql server at first